# How to render variable value from one function to another function in flask ,

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route("/su", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def data_value():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = request.form['context']
        question = request.form['question']
        data.append(d.Question_answer(context,question))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Context', 'Question', 'Answer'])
    Insert_data(df)
    return render_template("home.html", td = data)
    

@app.route("/data", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def Insert_data(df):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            d.insert_into_db(df, cursor) 
            print('parsed using normal parsing1_div .')

        except Exception as ex:`enter code here`
            print('db fail1 ')
            print(ex)
        return render_template("index.html")
```

from first function I want import df value to function to I tried, but I am getting error=== TypeError: Insert_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'

Answer (score 0):

Use `session`

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, session

...


@app.route("/su", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data_value():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['context'] = request.form['context']
        session['question'] = request.form['question']
        data.append(d.Question_answer(session['context'], session['question']))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Context', 'Question', 'Answer'])
    Insert_data(df)
    return render_template("home.html", td=data)


@app.route("/data", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def Insert_data():
    if 'context' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('data_value'))
    data = [d.Question_answer(session['context'], session['question'])]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Context', 'Question', 'Answer'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            d.insert_into_db(df, cursor)
            print('parsed using normal parsing1_div .')
        except Exception as ex:
            print('db fail1 ')
            print(ex)
        return render_template("index.html")
```